# C# WPF Stop/Catch Application Exit from Unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, wpf, exit, unmanaged

I'm using a 3rd party dll written in C# in a WPF application.  That dll that I am using, references some unmanaged C++ dlls and I am trying to debug a problem where my application just exits.  There are no errors, nothing in my windows event log, so I am assuming something somewhere is making a call to Exit.  I want to try and intercept the call to confirm my suspicions, but have not been able to.

I have a callback in App.xaml for the Exit event, but its not firing...

Is there anything else I can do to try and "catch" this exit call?

Comment: More probably is the case when an unmanaged dll causes a corrupt state exception, and the whole process gets killed.

Comment: You can try to subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` event, and then see if there is any exception thrown

Comment: You can capture a crash dump and then analyze it. [LocalDumps MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help you.

Comment: @AndroidJoker: would that be better than debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13567016/17034

Comment: @ThomasW. It would be exactly the same for the case of exception in unmanaged code. `FirstChangeException` will also work without debugging, and generally very useful to log exceptions along with `UnhandledException` event