# Possible Reasons for WinForm app failure

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Hi I have a windows forms project built on visual studio 2013. It has a .sdf database file and around 200 Mb audio tracks. 
I deployed my using ClickOnce deployment and all my tracks and database were deployed successfully with it.
The problem I am facing is, when I am running my app on another PC, after sometime the app throws an error Stating that application has stopped working and forces shutdown of the app.
Being a newbie, I dont know why it is doing this?
Is it because of any sort of memory issues like memory leak or stack full etc?
Or is it a problem of the PC.
My app has been configured to run 32 and 64 bit windows PC and I am publishing it after changing configuration to Release mode.
I just want to know the reasons why this can happen.
The error message does not say what the error is and in my code i gave the check to catch all global errors like this:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
Application.ThreadException+=Application_ThreadException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException+=CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

In the respective methods I am displaying a custom error message. The app does not show these also and directly shuts down. Does this mean there is no error in my code?
Note: I tried my application on only 1 other machine apart from mine.
But it was that machine which will be mostly running my app so I have to make it work on it without any errors of such kind

Comment: Have you checked the event log on the machine where it fails, to see if it has any additional information on the error?

Comment: You'll find an overview of the kind of problems you can't catch in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13567016/17034).  That question was closed, you are not supposed to ask about this kind of issue I guess.  You need a minidump to find out what went really wrong, not something you can tackle yet if you don't know what "event log" means.  Ask an experienced colleague to help you out.