# Console Application Crashing, not executing global try catch and UnhandledException

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have a Console application which look as below,

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
        // My Code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) 
{
    // The code.
}
```

In the above code neither the catch is firing nor UnhandledExceptionTrapper. It suddenly says application stopped working. Event viewer has no important info about crash. Event viewer says some file exist but when check nothing there. I am using .NET 4.6.1.

The code just pulls data from oracle (using dapper) and using TransactionScope.

**Edit:** We have found the culprit line. It was doing a Update in Oracle wrapped inside TransactionScope. The problem is that unable to catch these exception and its coming sometimes and failing most of the time. These are sample code that uses Dapper to update Oracle.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   UpdateOracleUsingDapperMethod();
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Related: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30422

Comment: It may have something to do with unmanaged libraries... Are you using one?

Comment: No I am using Dapper and Transaction Scope

Comment: A bunch of stuff needs to happen *before* your Main() method can run and subscribe the event.  The just-in-time compiler needs to run first, it can easily fail with a FileNotFoundException.  It is worse in the Release build, now it needs to try to inline method calls so more code needs to be jitted.  Any static variables with a field initializer are notable, may well run and keel over before Main() starts executing.  Make it better by moving the code in the `// My Code` block into another static method.  It needs [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining]) to slow down the jitter.

Comment: @HansPassant I can debug the first few lines of code but after than it crashes

Comment: Some exceptions are too nasty to handle and trigger a failfast.  Like the one this website is was named after, there [are others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567016/17034).  Look at the Output window for the process exit code.  Some can be reported anyway, look at [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39956163/17034).

Comment: @user960567 Could you start the application with some tool like WinDbg? You may get more information about the crash. This tool has been helpful to me so many times when weird crashes happen on the field :)

Comment: @HansPassant Kzrystop we found the reason for crash. It was simple Update statement in Oracle that make the application crash but sometimes it works and sometimes it crash.

Comment: @user960567 Out of curiosity, have you been able to get some information about the crash? Like the exception that seems to bypass the UnhandledException handler?

Comment: No info that's the problem. It seems there is exception on db side that is not caught.Unlucky so far.

Comment: Great thread - could it be that the exception is being "swallowed" somewhere (being caught deeper)?

Comment: @EdSF try is the first line and catch is last line and still crashes

Comment: @HansPassant andd Kzrystop moving OleDbConnection to OracleConnection fixed the crash issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: @user960567 Was it something like an access violation in unmanaged code?

Comment: @Kzrystof I don't have more info because I am using OleDbConnection abstraction don't know under the hood what it does. May be Hans knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue is related to `OleDbConnection`. So, we moved to `OracleConnection` and no crash. This means using Oracle in Dapper with `TransactionScope` and `OleDbConnection` have some serious issues.

Comment: Related https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30422