# Program crashes, but Debug Diag says it's a first chance exception, is that correct?

Tags: .net, debugging, first-chance-exception, debugdiag

Probably this is a normal situation, but I am confused.

I am running my C# Debug application from Visual Studio.  DebugDiag is set up to attach to the process automatically.

I have a rule to collect crash dumps from this application, and the rule defines that the action for unconfigured first chance exceptions should be "none".

But when the application crashes, and when I look at the dump files it says that there is a first chance exception.

From the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception), I understand that "exceptions are thrown to the debugger first and then to the actual program where if it isn't handled it gets thrown to the debugger a second time"

So why does DebugDiag collect dump files for the first chance exception?

EDIT
Just to be clear, I am not trying to fix broken code here.  I'm trying to understand why  DebugDiag told me that a first chance exception had made my code crash.  Surely by definition, only a 2nd chance exception can make code crash, i.e. one that has NOT been handled by the code?

"crash" means that the process terminated and DebugDiag generated crash dump files.  I was running the Debug version of the code on "Start without Debugging"

Comment: Without more context, this sounds impossible to answer. What is the specific meaning of "crashes" here? what is the exception? did you catch the exception? if so: where? was it perhaps on a worker thread? details...

Comment: Do you have any code, specifically for error handling? What exception is thrown? Have you stopped through the code, or tried anything else?

Comment: I have added some more to the question, which I hope will clarify what I am asking, and what I am not asking.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there are multiple exceptions in progress and the second chance is on another thread. Have you inspected all the thread stacks? `~*kb` should do it.

Comment: How do you find out that it's a first chance exception? Can you please post the output of WinDbg?