# A first chance exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException'

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I get an error like this:

> A first chance exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

while trying to update a table with duplicated Primary Key .

Problem is, I can't catch it even with a try-catch block.

```
try
    {
      res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
      {
        conn.Close();
      }
    }
```

I just want to show a MessageBox when I get the Exception so the user knows which table didn't change

UPDATE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5vGi.png)

Comment: Related: [What is a first-chance Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564681/812149).

Comment: The non-query that you try to execute - does it work if you give it in the DBMS directly, under the same privileges that the program has? It _might_ be relevant.

Comment: Please post the exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @Zoe I think the last edit lost something important - as I understand it, the OP _cannot_ catch the Exception .

Comment: @S.L.Barth When i execute the query in DBMS I get the Duplicated Primary Key error