# Visual Studio 2015 Output Exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently building an application which has become quite big. Even though the application is working fine, I am seeing in the "Output"-window a few Exceptions being thrown.
I would like to solve those exceptions but the Exceptions don't provide any information from which method they are coming.
So for example I get a `System.ObjectDisposedException`, but I don't really have an idea where it is being thrown.

Is there a way I can easily trace where this Exception is being thrown?

Thanks

Comment: Do those happen to be first-chance exceptions? [What is a “first chance exception”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception)

Comment: Maybe helpful [How to break on handled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681894/12417300)

Comment: Set as much debugging points as possible and try to find the method where it throws the exception.

Comment: I'm guessing it could be a first chance exception but I don't know for sure. Also setting as many debugging points as possible makes it almost impossible to debug...

Comment: The exception means that you try to use an object after it was Dispose()d. Possibly in a "using" statement. So look for that

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that in the Debugger under Exception Settings I can enable Exceptions to break on. So this way I can find where they are being thrown.