# can't catch "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException" in C#

Tags: c#, exception, ioexception

I made some code to read a file and have a problem with try-catch block.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:...\WpfApplicationExample\bin\Debug\KeyWord\ROS\KeyWord_Booting_Time.json'.

I always meet this exception although already handled it.
my directory does definitely not exist, but I already handle it by `catch` block, so why my app still crashes at this: `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath)`.

Please take a look at the code below and tell me what is the problem?

```
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
            jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.log(TAG, "getKeyWords", e.Message);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Log.log(TAG, "getKeyWords", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.log(TAG, "getKeyWords", e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: There is of course not point in catching 2 specific types of exceptions + a catch all exception if you are doing the same thing in each catch block!

Comment: Note the "first chance" language. Maybe you're debugging and have enabled first chance exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception

Comment: Are you sure that is it throws System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException? I think, StreamReader throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException when filePath does not exists

Comment: thank @Simon Mourier  for your information, I understand now.

Comment: @TrịnhVũLong - If you found your solution, answer yourself to close the question and gain some points

Answer (score 1):

for anyone has same problem: refer below docs for understanding about first chance and second chance exceptions.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidklinems/what-is-a-first-chance-exceptione]

my app is not really crash.. it just shows me a message to report me when an exception occurs.. if I click "continue" in message box.. it will keep running my app and land to catch block as expected.

FYI
thank all.